# Writing [Bool] to binary file using Haskell

Tags: haskell

Working in Haskell, I am trying to write a big list of booleans to a binary file.

I can write Word8 (which is a 8 bit word) to file, but can't figure out how to convert from an list of eight Bool to a Word8.

Here's what I have so far:

```
toByte :: [Bool] -> Word8
toByte list = toByteh list 0 0

toByteh :: [Bool] -> Int -> Word8 -> Word8
toByteh list 8 _ = 0
toByteh list i result 
    | head list == True = toByteh (tail list) (i + 1) (result .|. (2^i :: Word8))
    | otherwise = toByte_h (tail list) (i + 1) result
```

When I use this I just get a 0 byte. Can anyone see where this isn't working?
Or are there better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're counting up `i` from `0` and when you reach `8`, you return `0`. I think you meant to return `result` instead:

```
toByteh list 8 result = result
```

Answer (score 4):

It is always nice to write such functions, but if you start feeling bored, you may also

```
toByte = foldl (\word\bit -> 2*word + (if bit then 1 else 0)) 0
```

(Here, the head of the list is taken as the lowest bit, reverse if you dont like.)